# how to format multiple labels into a single legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I cannot seem to find a solution to this specific problem, so I hope someone can help (and that I haven't missed something).

I have data in long format for ggplot2 with two attributes I would like to put into the label in the legend. Sample dataset:

```
require(ggplot2)
ds1=data.frame("Heading"="Alpha","Val"=0.534,"x"=seq(1,5,1),"y"=(seq(10,2,-2)**1.5))
ds2=data.frame("Heading"="Beta","Val"=0.732,"x"=seq(1,5,1),"y"=seq(30,6,-6))
ds3=data.frame("Heading"="Carotene","Val"=0.877,"x"=seq(1,5,1),"y"=seq(3,15,3))
test1=rbind(ds1,ds2,ds3)
test1$Head1=factor(test1$Heading)
test1$Val=factor(test1$Val)
p5=ggplot(test1,mapping=aes(x=x,y=y,colour=Heading)) + geom_line(size=1)
print(p5)
```

That second piece of data, however, Val, I would also like to get into the legend. A suggestion I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19777492/how-to-format-labels-in-ggplot2-legend) used **interaction**:

```
p5 = ggplot(test1,mapping=aes(x=x,y=y,colour=interaction(Heading,Val,sep=" "))) + geom_line(size=1) + labs(colour="Heading")
```

which has all the information I wanted, but run together. Alternatively, I tried

```
p5=ggplot(test1,mapping=aes(x=x,y=y,colour=Heading)) + geom_line(size=1)
p5 + scale_colour_discrete(labels=paste(levels(test1$Heading)," (",levels(test1$Val),")",sep=""))
```

however for what I am really aiming, I would like to get the "Val" information formatted such that the appropriate number of spaces is inserted to separate them into columns. Like a data.frame, but with the legend/colour information for the plot as well. Or just to somehow right-justify that half (Val) leaving the first half of each line (Heading) left justified. Trying,

```
p5 = ggplot(test1,mapping=aes(x=x,y=y,colour=interaction(Heading,Val,sep="\t"))) + geom_line(size=1) + labs(colour="Heading")
```

to force a tab stop (hoping that might work in some machine-dependent manner), does not seem to work either, although using "\n" does (for space and clarity, I would like to keep the labels on one line, since there are 12 levels in the data I am plotting and I would like the viewer to be able to scan down the range of values easily). Thanks for any suggestions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're comfortable with reversing the value & label, this will give you the columns you seek:

```
test1$grouping <- sprintf("%s - %s", test1$Val, test1$Heading)
ggplot(test1,mapping=aes(x=x,y=y,colour=grouping)) + geom_line(size=1) + labs(colour="Heading")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that - I had a similar idea and I hope it's not being too picky, but I was hoping to preserve the order, as the "Heading" information is the more important and the "Val", while still relevant, is gravy. Might have to go with this though, if there's no other way of modifying the legend...

Comment: My only other thought that doesn't involve poking around at the grob level is to force a monospaced font for the legend and then using space-filling strings (e.g. via `sprintf`) might work.